# Time series : Nonlinear NARDL in R with a dummy variable for structural Breaks

Tags: r, ardl

I need help in estimating a nonlinear ARDL with dummy variables. I used "|" on the variable `logEPUNews` to decompose the positive and negative innovations. I would like to account for structural breaks using the dummy variable `D_Accom` as in the equation below. This variable is a dummy and should not be differenced. How do I specify this as a fixed variable in the nardl model in R?

```
reg <- nardl(logAccom ~ logEPUNews| + logTravcost + logGDPPCAP + logSPE + D_Accom, 
data = researchdata, ic =  "aic", maxlag = 3, graph = TRUE, case=5)
```